# How do I pass a parameter to a controller action within a Laravel Package?

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Within a Laravel package I made, I want to redirect the user to a controller action that requires a parameter (within the same package).

Controller:

```
public function postMatchItem(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'item_match' => 'required|numeric|exists:item,id',
    ]);

    $spot_buy_item = SpotBuyItem::find($id);

    $item = Item::find($request->input('item_match'));

    $price = $item->getPrice();

    $spot_buy_item_response = new SpotBuyItemResponse();
    $spot_buy_item_response->spot_buy_item_id = $id;
    $spot_buy_item_response->spot_buy_id = $spot_buy_item->spot_buy_id;
    $spot_buy_item_response->item_id = $item->id;
    $spot_buy_item_response->user_id = $spot_buy_item->user_id;
    $spot_buy_item_response->spot_buy_price = $price;
    $spot_buy_item_response->created_ts = Carbon::now();
    $spot_buy_item_response->save();

    return redirect()->action('Ariel\SpotBuy\Http\Controllers\Admin\SpotBuyController@getPart', [$id]);
}
```

The action in the redirect is the same path I use in my `routes.php` file to direct the user to this controller action

Route:

```
Route::get('/part/{id}', 'Ariel\SpotBuy\Http\Controllers\Admin\SpotBuyController@getPart')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

I've tried variations of this path without success, including `SpotBuyController@getPart` like the documentation suggests (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects)

**Note**: I got this to work by naming my route in `routes.php` and using `return redirect()->route('route_name', [$id]);`, but I still want to know how to pass a package controller action to the `->action()` function.

Comment: Try: `return redirect()->action('Ariel\SpotBuy\Http\Controllers\Admin\SpotBuyController@getPart', ['id' => $id]);`

Comment: No luck. I get the same error message: `production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Action App\Http\Controllers\Ariel\SpotBuy\Http\Controllers\Admin\SpotBuyController@getPart not defined.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's trying to access your controller from within the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace.  Can see they've added it to your controller name in your error:

`App\Http\Controllers\Ariel\SpotBuy\Http\Controllers\Admin\SpotBuyController@getP‌​art`

You need to escape the `Ariel` namespace with a `\` at the start:

```
return redirect()->action('\Ariel\SpotBuy\Http\Controllers\Admin\SpotBuyController@getPart', [$id]);
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: Nice answer! Sometimes, big problems are in small details!! +1